# MY CAT ATE a bit of L'Oreal Paris Oreor 30 Volume Creme Developer will he be fine?

Tags: cats

So last night my friend bought L'Oreal Paris Oreor 30 Volume Creme Developer and forgot to take it and left it on the floor. I went to sleep but come to find the next morning the L'Oreal Paris Oreor 30 Volume Creme Developer. The bag was all chewed up and the developer was on the floor with a hole on it. I picked it up as the developer starts to burn my hand. I start to freak out since I’m a male and have no clue on what this is. I call my friend and she has no clue if it can harm my cat. My cat looks fine but I’m afraid that it hasn’t sunk in yet or if the cat lost its sense of taste or if he will have any other problems? I’ve been searching trying to look for answers but nothing pops up. Please help

Comment: I don't know what creme developer is, but could you add the photo of the ingredients on the box?

Comment: If your cat has ingested a potentially harmful chemical, CONTACT YOUR VET IMMEDIATELY! Do not wait around for strangers on the internet to answer your question!

Comment: Update: My cat Appears fine and it’s been over 8 hours there is no sign of poison or anything. I’ll probably end up going to the vet since I want to be 100% sure that nothing is wrong. P.S. the vets around my area really aren’t the best and all they want is money. They called me one time and today me that because my cat is over a year old they will need a second rabies shot. That was really weird since my cat was at the time only 7 months. A asked for the cats name and it was indeed my cat. So that’s the reason why I didn’t go to the vet in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEDICAL EMERGENCY!

Your cat may have ingested Hydrogen Peroxide which is never safe for cats! Take your cat to the vet immediately as hydrogen peroxide is never safe for cats according to [PetPoisonhelpline.com](https://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/pet-safety-tips/five-pet-poisoning-first-aid-misconceptions/#:%7E:text=Hydrogen%20peroxide%20is%20often%20used,been%20fatal%20to%20some%20cats.)